# Indian Passport nearing 6 months validity, Will it be a problem to travel to Australia without its renewal though a Valid 2yrs Visa is available

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, australia

My Indian passport expires on 15th December 2019. I hold a WPLT for 2 years. I'm planning to travel Australia around 6th June 2019.

Questions

- Is there any 6 months restriction on Indian passports in Australia
- Will it cause any issue with Immigration Services during
  checks in India or Australia.
- Should I get my Passport renewed before I travel?

Answer (score 4):

Australia does not have a six month passport validity rule. Your passport only needs to be ["current [and] valid"](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/entering-australia/crossing-the-border) when you arrive, according to the Department of Home Affairs.